# Printing a binary tree whose elements are stored in a array

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-tree

I want to print a complete binary tree with n elements where 1<=n<=m & m is a natural number and these elements are stored in an array.
My approach :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];
    for(int a=0;a<n;a++)cin>>arr[a];

    /*Printing the sorted tree*/
    int l=1,cnt=1;
    while(l<=n)
    {
        cnt++;
        l=l+pow(2,cnt);
    }
    int val=0,cn=1,loli;
    while(1)
    {
        for(int p=cnt;p>=1;p--) cout<<"   ";
        for(int ll=1,loli=1;ll<=pow(2,val);ll++){
                if(cn==n)return 0;
                if(loli!=2){
                    cout<<arr[cn++]<<"    ";
                    loli++;
                }
                else{
                    cout<<arr[cn++];
                    loli=1;
                }
        }
        val++;
        cnt=cnt-2;
        if(cnt==0)cnt=1;
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output of this code done by me]

[image: My desired output]

I found some related answers [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484943/print-a-binary-tree-in-a-pretty-way) . But the discussion is using link list may be (nodes) where I do not want to use nodes for taking elements of tree. I am taking them from an array.

Comment: Don't give output as a screenshot of your entire desktop. Post it as [formatted] text. And if you _really_ must link to an image, at least use some caption a little more imaginative than "enter image description here"?

Comment: `int n; cin>>n; int arr[n];` isn't standard C++

Comment: `pow(2,cnt)` == `1 << cnt` with a lot less work and potential floating point madness.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to follow your code because:

1. It's not clear how you're approaching this problem
2. You don't break into functions (which you should)
3. You use cryptic names for variables
4. You have a strange dependence on an entirely artificial parameter, m. Why do we care about m at all?

If you follow better practices solving this problem - starting with describing your algorithm clearly (to yourself if to no-one else) - you will probably get it right.

Comment: Saying m, I tried to clear that array size is not fixed. It can varry.

Comment: @kalaMask: The array length = tree size is your parameter n. Just say it's not known at compile time, that's it.