# Function to print BST in C++

Tags: c++, struct, binary-search-tree

Helo,
I'm looking for help to write as easy as possible for me to understand function to print out BST in pretty way. Like

```
  50
 /  \
30  70
```

Here's my code which adds elements to tree:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int key;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};
struct node *root;

struct node *make_leaf(int new_data);
struct node *add_node(struct node* root, int key);

int main()
{
   node *root = NULL;
   int new_element, how;
   cout<<"How many elements?"<<endl;
   cin>>how;
   for(int i=0; i<how; ++i){
   cout<<"Enter element value"<<endl;
   cin>>new_element;
   root = add_node(root, new_element);
   }
return 0;
}
struct node* make_leaf(int new_data){
       node *nd=new node;
       nd->key=new_data;
       nd->left=NULL;
       nd->right=NULL;
       return nd;

}
struct node *add_node(struct node* root, int key){
    if (root==NULL)
    {
        return make_leaf(key);
    }
    else
    {
        if (root->key > key)
        {
            root->left = add_node(root->left, key);
        }
        else
        {
            root->right = add_node(root->right, key);
        }
    }
    return root;
 }
```

I'm looking for help but I'm starting my adventure with programming so please don't get angry at me :) Thank you!

***EDIT***

I've tried below function but it's not writing the node root at the top as it should be :/

```
void postorder(struct node * root, int indent)
{
    if(root != NULL) {

        if(root->right) {
            postorder(root->right, indent+4);
        }
        if (indent) {
            cout << setw(indent) << ' ';
        }
        if (root->right) cout<<" /\n" << setw(indent) << ' ';
        if(root->left) {
            cout << setw(indent) << ' ' <<" \\\n";
            postorder(root->left, indent+4);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484943/print-a-binary-tree-in-a-pretty-way

Comment: If you look at your `postorder` function, you will see that if there is only a root node, that node is not printed.  You need to revisit your `postorder` logic, as it doesn't even work for the simplest case of a tree having only a single root node.  Maybe start by removing the "fancy indent" stuff and concentrate on printing each node during the traversal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new is reserved keyword. please change name of variable "new" to something else.

changing new to new1 compile your program.

Comment: Thank you, Done :)

Comment: But It still didn't fixed my problem with printing function :/