# How to display binary tree in C# console

Tags: c#, binary-tree

How do I display the binary tree in a pretty formatted manner in C# console.
My tree is in following format

Comment: internal class BinaryTree
    {
        public int Root { get; set; }
        public BinaryTree Left { get; set; }
        public BinaryTree Right { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58468624/edit) your question to include your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print a binary tree in a pretty way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484943/print-a-binary-tree-in-a-pretty-way)

Answer (score 0):

Serialise to json and print that json.

Example with .NET Core 3

```
var options = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions() {WriteIndented = true};
var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer(myBinaryTree, options); 

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Example with [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```